# How can I use geolocation in my node.js to get user device lat/long

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, geolocation

Good day all, pardon my question logic as I am new here. I am building my first fullstack App using React and Node.I am thinking of three approaches but not sure what will work best.

**APPROACH ONE**

I want to be able to get user lat/long when they fill a form in the frontend and request access to their geolocation through the geolocation API. For example, when a user submit their region and community name, the backend will call the  getCurrentPosition geolocation API. Then the returned lat/long will form part of the data to be sent to the database as shown in the extracted code below. But when I tried this approach, I ran into two challenges. First, an error message that `navigator is not defined`. Second, I don't know how to retrieved the lat/long returned and declare it as a const to use it in creating the location. See the code below:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  } else {
    alert("Your browser is out of fashion. There is no geo location!")
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude 
    console.log(`Your latitude is ${latitude} and your longitude is ${longitude}`)
      return (latitude, longitude);
  }

  function error() {
    alert("Can't detect your location. Try again later.")
  }
```

How do I declare the lat/long as a const outside the function. Some like:

```
 const communityName = req.body.communityName;
 const latitude = (success).latitude;
 const longitude = (success).longitude;
```

**APPROACH 2**

I downloaded the geolocation npm package and use it as in code below but get the error that navigator is not defined. If I am to use this approach, how can I define navigator and how can I get to declare the lat/long as a const outside of the function?

```
const geolocation = require('geolocation');

geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (err, position) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(position)
  })
```

**APPROACH 3**

I read about this approach but can't get a working example. It is suggested that I should use the geolocation API to get the user device lat/long and send the coords as part of req.body data to the backend API. If this is a good approach, is there a tutorial I can follow?

Please I am new to Javascript and coding but I have made serious progress but this as got me stocked on my project. No answer is too wrong lease. There is sense in nonsense.

Answer (score 4):

> navigator.geolocation

This is an API provided by browsers. It isn't available to Node.js.

> I downloaded the geolocation npm package

This wraps `navigator.geolocation`. It is designed for when you are writing client-code code using Node modules and a compilation step such as provided by Webpack. It doesn't work with Node.js.

> It is suggested that I should use the geolocation API to get the user device lat/long and send the coords as part of req.body data to the backend API.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) both provide introductions to the `fetch` API for making HTTP requests from client-side JavaScript.

There is also some [React-specific information](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) in the React FAQ.

You can then read the data *in a different endpoint* with [`req.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) providing you have configured a suitable body-parsing middleware.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin I'll look into the 3rd step.