# Getting error while testing for geolocation in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, next.js

I am trying to use geolocation API in my app. Luckily I found one that I'd like to use at the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API/Using_the_Geolocation_API), but when I tried testing for the geolocation object (if it exists in the browser) I got this error:

> Server Error
> ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
>
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
> Source pages/index.js (24:20) @ eval
>
> ```
>   22 | }
>   23 | 
> > 24 | if('geolocation' in navigator) {
>      |                    ^
>   25 |   console.log('It does exist')
>   26 | } else {
>   27 |   console.log('doesn't exist')
> ```

This is the code I tried implementing (from the MDN docs website) :

```js
if('geolocation' in navigator) {
  /* geolocation is available */
} else {
  /* geolocation IS NOT available */
}
```

Can you let me know what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using React?

Comment: Is this executed on a server (`Server Error`, _" Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window"_)?

Comment: @showdev Yes sir. Next JS to be precise. Would that be the problem?

Comment: @ChrisBBB Are you testing from local? (like localhost:port} As it won't work in `HTTP` connection, only works in `HTTPS` protocol.
`This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS).`

Comment: These and similar posts seem relevant: [How can I use geolocation in my node.js to get user device lat/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696252/how-can-i-use-geolocation-in-my-node-js-to-get-user-device-lat-long) and [Navigator not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910623/requireprocessing-js-throws-reference-error-navigator-not-found) and [navigator is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194264/mocha-react-navigator-is-not-defined)

Comment: @sidverma - Yes, I am testing from local.

Comment: @ChrisBBB Then what I have told you is correct, you should either deploy on some secure HTTPS connection.[try ngrok]. 
Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `window` object on the server. When you want to work with the `window` object you need to do it on the **client** side. So in your react component, you need to use `useEffect` as this function only runs in the browser.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  if('geolocation' in navigator) {
    /* geolocation is available */
  } else {
    /* geolocation IS NOT available */
  }
},[])
```

The function inside `useEffect` will run when the component is mounted in the browser.